# check every input has value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Html

```
<input type="text" name="test[]" class="test">
```

How can I check every input has value? This is what I tried but if one the input has value it will not alert the **message**

Script

```
var x = new Array();
var message = "";

jQuery("input[name='test[]']").each(function(){
  var y = jQuery(this).val().toLowerCase();
  if(y){
    x.push(y);
  }
});

if(x.length === 0){
  message += "missing";
};

if(message != ""){
  alert(message);
}
```

EDIT
I want to alert if one of input has no value

Comment: did you want it to alert if the input has a value? or what did you want to happen?

Comment: @Rick I want to alert it no value if one of input is no value

Comment: seems to work fine here..

Comment: @Rick yes but it doesnt alert if one of input has value

Comment: ah well you only had one input so I guess I didn't catch on to what you were asking..

Comment: @Rick ahh yes thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will alert 'no value' if one of the inputs has no value. Just check the `$.val()` and alert and break the loop if it doesn't return anything.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {

  $("input[name='test[]']").each(function() {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
      alert('no value');
      return false;
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="test[]" class="test">
<input type="text" name="test[]" class="test">
<input type="text" name="test[]" class="test">
<button>validate</button>
```

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization awesome, no problem: )